# javascript onsubmit without submit button, by enter via keyboard

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

I have this piece of html code:

```
<form id="cambia_stato" method="get" action="">
<input type="text" name="stato" id="frase_stato" value=""
onclick="this.value='';" onblur="setMessaggio()" maxlength="255"
/>
</form>
```

and I want to check the value of the "stato" field on submit.
I tried two ways: 
using **onsubmit** is not triggered by pressing the Enter key:

```
<!-- nothing happens with the following -->
<form id="cambia_stato" method="get" action="" onsubmit="myFunc()">
```

So I tried checking the input each time a key is pressed, changing the input attributes adding a **onkeypressed** event:

```
<!-- nothing happens with the following -->
<input type="text" name="stato" id="frase_stato" value=""
onclick="this.value='';" onblur="setMessaggio()" maxlength="255"
onkeypressed="myFunc()" />
```

For now, the function myFunc() is defined as follow:

```
function myFunc ()
{
    alert('test');
}
```

Am I going wrong somewhere or do I need a submit button?

Comment: not really, thanks though

Comment: Yes really. Look at some of the other answers and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=submit+enter

Comment: you're right,sorry about that. I'm quite new here, I'll learn how to better search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your javascript.  This will capture the enter key.

```
    document.onkeydown = function () {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            myFunc();
        }
    };
```